# ARM: What to do with the stack pointer?

Tags: pointers, assembly, arm, raspberry-pi3

I have the following piece of ARM Assembly Code from my professor. 
I do not understand why i need to move the stack pointer to r1 and what happens exactly.

I know from the lecture, that ...

> The stack pointer is pointing to the last written value on the stack.

Does pointing to always mean that the address is stored?
I managed to get the code working. But i want to improve code quality and understand what's going on. Also i am not allowed to use arithmetic operations anywhere in the program.
i tried the debugger also. but i only figured out how to watch the program counter from there. 
I used

```
info registers sp pc
```

and

```
disas
```

I searched through all the options of the debugger but could not find something helpful.

In the stack pointer register is stored - i guessed - some address value.

```
// scan for users answer 'y'
ldr     r0, =charplace
mov     r1, sp              @ ???
bl      scanf               @ Scan user's answer
ldr     r1, =yes            @ Put address of 'y' in r1
ldrb    r1, [r1]            @ Load the actual character 'y' into r1
```

at the start of the main function i do this:

```
        .global main
main:                   
     push   {r4 - r7, lr}   @ copy values of these reg on top of the stack
     sub     sp, sp, #4     @ needs to be replaced ! TODO
```

and at the end this:

```
end: add    sp, sp, #4      @ needs to be replaced ! TODO
     pop    {r4 - r7, pc}   @ copy values from the top of the stack back into these registers
```

Comment: That TODO can be resolved by commenting out the `add/sub` and changing something about that `push/pop` instructions. And if your debugger happens to be `gdb`, you may try [`layout asm` `layout regs`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/TUI-Commands.html), although I'm not sure if it will work on your target platform.

Comment: And yes, the value in `sp` register is usually valid address into memory, which is reserved for "stack" (it's just ordinary memory and pointer to it, the `push/pop` functionality can be sort of emulated by storing/loading value into memory+updating pointers in principle, the `push/pop` are just shorter to write, and they are usually atomic (or at least easier to make them atomic by some kind of `lock` prefix))

Comment: OK. thanks for the hints. i tried `layout asm` `layout regs`. it looks good at the start but breaks down after a short time. i do not know what to change about the instructions. that's why i was asking. :3

Comment: Well, if you will understand how `push/pop` with multiple registers work, you will surely figure out how to make them also do additional +-4 to `sp`. Although it's not exact replacement of `add/sub`, as it will have additional side effect, so you have to also consider which adjustment will have harmless side effect, considering used calling convention. Just check the ARM docs for the details of those instructions and imagine how they work and what happens to the `sp` and other registers.

Comment: `main.s: Assembler messages:
main.s:22: Warning: if writeback register is in list, it must be the lowest reg in the list
main.s:144: Warning: writeback of base register when in register list is UNPREDICTABLE
`

Comment: I guess you added `sp` into list of registers to push/pop, so you didn't understand how it works and what the original code does. Keep debugging + watching, stop guessing. IIRC ARM has 15 or 16 registers, so that multi-push alone has 32k or 64k variants, that's a lot to "guess" it right.

Answer (score 2):

The `sub sp, sp, #4` allocates 4 bytes of space for a buffer. With a full descending stack, `sp` will point to the start of that buffer, with the other 3 bytes being at `sp+1`, `sp+2`, and `sp+3` of course. The reason to move `sp` to `r1` is that `scanf` needs the buffer address as second argument and `r1` is used to pass that.

In `gdb` you can examine memory using the `x` command, to see the stack you can do for example `x/4x $sp`. See `help x` for format specifiers.

Comment: thank you. x seems to be useful. but its helps me not so much now, because i do not know what to examine in memory. :)

Comment: your answer is very useful. why does `scanf` need a buffer but calling one of my functions makes it not necessary to create some space below the stack?

Comment: Do you know how `scanf` works? In C? You realize it needs space to store the conversion result. That's what you allocated.

Comment: no that's the problem we do not learn C. we learn assembly (MMIX) in 1. and 2. semester. now its my 3. semester with assembly and i do not know much about C still. Yeah but OK i will just accept that it needs some space to return the result. The user input. Therefore needs 4 bytes but can't use a register to transmit its return value, because it is not an assembly procedure. Makes sense.